# Alignment of three buttons in Table Row Android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I have three buttons in my Actvity inside Linear Layout.
Here i wish all buttons should occupy whole tablelayour equally.
So i have coded as below.

```
<Linearlayout>
 ......
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registerTwitter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register Twitter" 
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registerFB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register FaceBook" 
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clearCredentials"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Clear Credentials"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

But here when i gave code as above i got three buttons occupying whole space.

but alignment are not proper. They are like dancing in air....

where did i made mistake...

[image: This is the part of output i got]

**Also note above Last button is not visible fully its half hidden.....**

I'm really weak in UI design can anyone suggest in that ....

Comment: A little difficult to understand what you are wanting. Maybe draw an image of what you are wanting and let us see it.

Comment: @prolink007 as Craigy said i need to get all the buttons in same line. without each flying in air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity and layout_gravity are two different fields on your buttons.

Gravity alters the positions of the text in the button and layout_gravity alters the buttons layout position

You have one button using layout_gravity and the other two using gravity.
Make sure you use the right ones!

Edit, here try this code, it is better to use weights:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerTwitter"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register Twitter" 
        android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerFB"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register FaceBook" 
        android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearCredentials"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Credentials"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight=".3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: using .3 weight will accomplish my goal? coz i have used that also in my same code but i couldn' get it.. anyways i will try ur code  and get back

Comment: Well, .3 is just a suggestion. Because you have 3 buttons, it is easy to think of it as a percentage. Just how I do it, but you can use any number.

Comment: MrZander this is giving just giving three buttons in a row.. but its not occupying whole space from parent evenly

Comment: MrZander im confused dude.. When i'm devloping application ur layout design seems to be like it s not correct one.. but if i run it its occupying whole space how come this is happening?

Comment: So it isn't WYSIWYG? Make sure that you have fully updated your android sdk tools. Do you want it to occupy the whole space?

Comment: yes at last i got it while i run my application. but when i design it, buttons are just wrap_content !!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want the buttons to be given equal horizontal space in a row, then try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    ... other views here ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerTwitter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Register Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerFB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Register FaceBook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearCredentials"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear Credentials" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This tells the buttons to start out with width `0` and divide up the remaining horizontal space equally amongst themselves.

Comment: Craigy this is just a linear layout this doesnot occupies whole space.,,,,

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I have changed the `layout_width` of the LinearLayout containing the buttons to `fill_parent`. Also changed the heights of the buttons to `fill_parent`

Comment: ya its fine now. thanks... but previously when i did with ur code also i got sort of correct output.. i mean when i devlop appliction in Graphical layout it seems to wrong but when i run app it occpies whole space even before when it was wrap_content?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... does it work correctly both places with these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You mix `gravity` and `layout_gravity`. You should use `layout_gravity`. Moreover, be aware that the `center` value means horizontal center AND vertical center. That may explain why your middle button is vertically off.

Comment: So you mean i should use Layout_Gravity? if i use so buttons are not filling whole spaces even if i give fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by implementing in relativelayout instead of linearlayout as below

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:text="Button1"

  />
 <Button 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="Button2"
  />
  <Button 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/button3"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:text="Button3"
  />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: deepa this is not working this collapes parent linear layout as well

Comment: Just replace this relativelayout instead of linearlayout in tablelayout. can you explain little more what you got?